# Find the equation of the plane that has distance $1$ from line $X: (1,0,2) + \lambda (1,0,2)$ and contains points $P=(1,1,-1)$ and $Q = (2,1,1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I am asked the following problem:

> Find the equation of the plane that has distance $1$ from line $X: (1,0,2) + \lambda (1,0,2)$ and contains points $P=(1,1,-1)$ and $Q = (2,1,1)$

Let's call the normal vector of the plane $\vec{n}$ so that $\vec{n} = (a,b,c)$

What I have so far is:

I) Since the distance from the plane and the line is $1$, using the point $(1,0,2)$ from the line and the normal vector of the plane,

$$
d_{istance} = 1 = \frac{\vert 1 a + 0 b + 2 c + d \vert }{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\\
1 = \frac{\vert a+2c+d \vert }{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}
$$

II) Since the plane must be parallel to the line, the dot product between the normal vector and $(1,0,2)$ must be zero:

$$
(a,b,c) \cdot (1,0,2) = 0\\
a+2c = 0
$$

III) Since points $P$ and $Q$ are contained on the plane,

$$
a+b-c+d=0\\
2a+b+c+d = 0
$$

I'm stuck on this part: there are more variables than equations to solve (If we combine the equations in III we get equation II). Is there something else that I'm missing?

**Textbook's answer:** $y-1=0$ and $6x-2y-3z-7=0$

Thank you.

Comment: You have 4 equations and 4 unknowns..what else do you need?

Comment: Equation number II is a linear combination of equations in number III

Answer (score 1, accepted):

($d=1$ can be taken arbitrarily here. If another value is chosen, the values for $a,b,c$ are scaled by a factor of $d$ and the same plane equations result.)

$$1=\frac{|a+2c+1|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\tag1$$
$$a+b-c=-1\tag2$$
$$2a+b+c=-1\tag3$$
$$a+2c=0\tag4$$
Substitute (4) into (1) twice:
$$1=\frac{|0+1|}{\sqrt{(-2c)^2+b^2+c^2}}$$
$$1=\frac1{\sqrt{5c^2+b^2}}$$
$$5c^2+b^2=1\tag5$$
Substitute (4) and (5) into (2) to leave an equation in $c$ only:
$$-2c+\sqrt{1-5c^2}-c=-1$$
$$\sqrt{1-5c^2}=3c-1$$
$$1-5c^2=9c^2-6c+1$$
$$14c^2-6c=0$$
from which we get $c=0$ or $c=\frac37$. For both cases substitute into (4) and then (2) to get two possible normals:
$$a=0,b=-1,c=0$$
$$a=-\frac67,b=\frac27,c=\frac37$$
(2) establishes that $(a,b,c)\cdot P=-1$ in both cases, so we have the plane equations
$$-y=-1,\quad-\frac67x+\frac27y+\frac37z=-1$$
which rearrange to the given answers of
$$y-1=0,\quad 6x-2y-3z-7=0$$

Comment: Parcly did you assum that $d=1$? If so, I should have written it better: d and distance are two different things.

Comment: In equation (I) you put that $d=1$.

Comment: I know, but I meant distance. I just corrected that, sorry. It was a huge coincidence that your answer worked.
I am guessing we need another equation to solve this.

Comment: Hey. It turns out that we can set $d$ to any value we want, and $a,b,c$ will be scaled from my values by a factor of $d$. The same plane equations will always result regardless of the initial choice of $d$. So I can take $d=1$ arbitrarily.

Comment: Thats a great insight Parcly, thank you for that. I would include a remark on your answer: d cannot be zero, right?
Thank you.